Issue with GPS on RPi4 at boot
So I have RPi4 which I configured with multiple UARTs and a Ublox ZED-F9P on a custom designed board. My setup would use the UART1 on the F9P for ubx messages and the UART1 for NMEA messages that used by GPSD and Chrony for time purposes (together with the PPS).
I wrote a python script that configures the F9P so that both UARTs are correctly configured, and the script works.
Now, I want to do the second step and do it automatically at startup. I decided to use systemd and set a unit type as simple and target multi-user. The unit starts with no error but nothing is coming out from the GPS (check on both GPSMON and journalctl adding print statements). I stopped the unit, I got at that point something out and now GPSMON works (hence I configured it correctly). If I restart the unit everything works, with no problem (no computer restarting). I tried to do the same changing the target to default with the same result. At this point I decided to try and go back to rc.local and I am having same behaviour (at boot no error but nothing coming out, then stopping and restarting and everything is good). The only solution that I found at the moment is to keep enabled the unit so that it starts at startup and then stop and re-starting again on rc.local.
Any idea of what is happening?
